# Chrome Extension browser_action form

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
<html>
    <input id="form_input_1">
    <input id="form_input_2">
    <button id="form_button">Calculate</button>
    <div id="div_1"></div>
</html>
```

I made a chrome extension as a "browser_action".

What I want to do it this in the popup:

```
<script>
    var num1 = document.getElementById('form_input_1').value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById('form_input_2').value;

    var answer = num1 + num2;

    document.getElementById('div_1').innerHTML = answer;
</script>
```

But everything i try i keep getting errors:

- Refuses to run inline event handlers
- Refuses to execute...
- Cannot read property

I have done web development for 6 years and I know this is a dumb question, but does anyone have references or know where I can see something similar.

I tried checking stackoverflow and google, but all I could find was information about changing the page or tab your on. I just want to change the popup.

I've spent 5 hours on this and I could use some good leads.

Oddly enough, i've never used java and i made an app in 2 hours that accomplished this same thing, so i'm sure i'm missing something very simple.

> Sorry for my english, pleased edit grammar if you see anything.

Comment: Simply use a separate js file via `<script src="foo.js"></script>` element.

Comment: I have done this, i've used inline, external, and even the manifest.

Comment: Then there's something else. I suggest modifying any [demo extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples), shouldn't take more than a couple of minutes. Also, make sure to read the [overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview).

Comment: BTW a common pitfall is including js file in `<head>` and not using DOMContentLoaded before accessing the elements.

Comment: I did up DOMContentLoaded, but just like you said it was in the head.
After i put it on the bottom everything worked.  I knew it had to be something so small that i was overlooking.  Thanks wOxxOm!

Answer (score 1):

wOxxOm answered this question.

I was using DOMContentLoaded, but for some reason, it still wasn't working.

After taking his suggestion to move the js file to the bottom of the popup.html everything works.

```
<html>
<body>
    <input id="form_input_1">
    <input id="form_input_2">
    <button id="form_button">Calculate</button>
    <div id="div_1"></div>
</body>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

> Note: I tried my old code on windows and it worked while this solution works for windows and linux. Also, when i packed the extension the old code works on linux.  I don't know why this is.

Thanks everyone for the help even though it was a dumb question!

Comment: _"I was using DOMContentLoaded, but for some reason, it still wasn't working."_ My guess would be that your script actually ran after `DOMContentLoaded` was triggered: a race condition caused by an extremely simple and fast to load page.

Comment: That could be, I will keep an eye one for that thanks Xan.

Also tried it with jquery no problem.  I never saw something like this before. 

Normally DOMContent always works for standard web pages, but like you say, the page for only 6 lines.